# Can a class contain as a member a Base class which is later specialized to a Derived class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class, base-class

Can I have a class ("BIG") which has another class as a member (of type "Base"), so that upon construction, this "Base" member will actually be set to a derived class?

In particular, I want to have

```
class Base{
  public:
    void dostuff(){};
};

class DerivedA : public Base{
  public:
    void dostuff(){
     //implementation version A 
    }
};


class DerivedB : public Base{
  public:
    void dostuff(){
     //implementation version B 
    }
};

class BIG{
 Base mything;

 BIG(int Type){
  if (Type==0)
   mything=DerivedA();
  if (Type==1)
   mything=DerivedB();
 }
};
```

Does C++ not allow this.  In particular, I would be "Downcasting" mything from a Base to a DerivedA or a DerivedB.  Am I correct that Downcasting is only allowed from Base *pointers* to Derived *pointers*, and only when the Base pointer is actually already a pointer to a Derived class?

Comment: Yes of course that's possible. Please clarify what's your particular problem doing so. Did you mean to use a reference or pointer member rather than a sliced instance?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any inheritance anywhere...did you forget to add it in your example?

Comment: You need to use a pointer or a reference. These thing are specially designed to point/refer to objects of a derived class. (Provided you do actually have a derived class; there isn't any in the posted code)

Comment: There is no downcasting anywhere here...? `Base* mything = new DerivedA();` would be a classical polymorphism, where you assign a derived class object to a base class pointer. `BIG` looks like an implementation of Factory pattern (or a flavour of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you probably forgot to actually derive from `Base`. But anyway, polymorphism requires a pointer or a reference. Otherwise, assigning an object of a derived class to a variable of the base class' type will "slice" the derived class object, i.e. it will cut a base class object out of the derived class object:

```
class Base{
  public:
    virtual void dostuff(){ cout << "in base" << endl; };
};

class DerivedA : public Base {
  public:
    virtual void dostuff(){ cout << "in derived" << endl; };
};

int main() {

  Base mything = DerivedA();  // slicing, will result in a `Base`-object
  mything.dostuff(); // Base class implementation

  Base *polymorph = new DerivedA(); // polymorphic; will point to a DerivedA-instance
  polymorph->dostuff(); // DerivedA class implementation of dostuff



}
```

Comment: " polymorphism requires a pointer or a reference" is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but mything must be a pointer or a reference to a polymorphic object.  If you keep it as a plain object, you would have [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

```
class BIG{
    Base *mything;

public: 
    BIG(int Type){
        if (Type==0)
           mything = new DerivedA();
        else if (Type==1)
           mything = new DerivedB();
    }
};
```

Of course, this suppose that both `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` inherit publicly from `Base`. If you want the right `dostuff()` function to be called, you also need to make it `virtual` (this is not specific to your problem, but to polymorphic classes), as well as have a virtual destructor.

Finally, you'd need to take care of the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) if you don't want to suffer from nasty allocation/deallocation errors.  A more convenient alterative is therefore to use a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer and let the smart pointer take care of copies, and destruction.

*Comment: it's a question of style which is irrelevant here, but try to take the good habits and avoid an all cap class name ;-)*